# Nullreference Error on running C# in LinqPad

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, linqpad

I am learning C# and i get this weird error while trying out example in LinqPad.

```
public class UnitConverter
{   
    int ratio;
    public UnitConverter(int UnitRatio)
    {
        ratio = UnitRatio;
    }

    public int Convert(int data)
    {
        return ratio * data;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        UnitConverter FeetToInchesConverter = new UnitConverter(12);
        Console.WriteLine(FeetToInchesConverter.Convert(10));
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What wrong am i doing ?

Comment: Note that this sample, along with all the others in Chapters 2-10, 14, 20, 22, 23 and 26 of C# 5 in a Nutshell, are available as pre-loaded interactive samples in LINQPad. Go to LINQPad's samples tree view (bottom left) and click Download more samples to get all of the above chapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the Class around the method main

```
static void Main()
{
    UnitConverter FeetToInchesConverter = new UnitConverter(12);
    Console.WriteLine(FeetToInchesConverter.Convert(10));
}
```

The `Main` method is part of the internal class `UserQuery` and it is used as entry point for your script. So, if you hide it inside your own class then, probably, LinqPAD cannot find the entry point. What happen next is probably some invalid reference. For example, if you remove all the code of the class Test (Main included) LimqPAD raises the same error

Comment: Why is that ? Can you explain it a bit.

Comment: @ajkumar25 because you're running this sample in LinqPad, it takes care of creating the class that contains the `Main()` method for you. You'd need it, if you were running this in Visual Studio, for example.

Comment: The Main method is part of the class UserQuery and it is used as entry point for your script. So, if you hide it inside your own class then, probably, LinqPAD cannot find the entry point

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `main()` is in class, in order to run the program in LINQPad remove the `class Test` around the `main()` method

Comment: While running in VS, wrapping main in class will work or not ?

Comment: While running in VS your `Main()` should be wrapped in a class. Usually the class name is the name of the project. and that `Main` method is used for entry into your program.